# Converting SQL query to Hive query

Tags: sql, database, hadoop, hive

I am having some trouble converting my SQL queries into Hive queries.

Relational schema:

```
Suppliers(sid, sname, address)
Parts(pid, pname, color)
Catalog(sid, pid, cost)
```

Query 1: Find the pnames of parts for which there is some supplier.
I have attempted one of the query conversions for query 1 and I think it is correct If someone can let me know if it is correct or incorrect I would really appreciate it. They seem to be the same to me based on the info I have looked up for Hive.

**Query 1: SQL**

```
SELECT pname
FROM Parts, Catalog
WHERE Parts.pid = Catalog.pid
```

**Query 1: Converted to Hive**

```
SELECT pname
FROM Parts, Catalog
WHERE Parts.pid = Catalog.pid;
```

Query 2: Find the sids of suppliers who supply only red parts. 
For the second query I am having trouble. Mainly I am having trouble with the "not exists" part and the defining what color we want part. Can someone help me figure this out? I need to put the SQL into a Hive query.

**Query 2: SQL**

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.sid
FROM Catalog C
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                   FROM Parts P
                   WHERE P.pid = C.pid AND P.color <> ‘Red’)
```

If someone can help me get these into the correct Hive format I would really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: You should start using Joins, in both HiveQL and standard SQL.

Comment: Which version of Hive? 0.12+ should support NOT EXISTS: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries#LanguageManualSubQueries-SubqueriesintheWHEREClause

Answer (score 0):

Although I have never used HiveQL in looking up some of its documentation it appears to support outer joins written in plain sql. In that case this should work: (an outer join where there is no match)

```
select distinct c.id
  from catalog c
  left outer join parts p
    on (c.pid = p.pid
   and p.color <> 'Red')
 where p.pid is null
```

Edit -- enclosed on clause in `()` , this is not normally required of any major databases but seems to be needed in hiveql -- (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins).

Regarding your first query I don't think it wouldn't work in hive based on example queries in those docs however as another commenter mentioned it is best practice to use explicit joins via the join clause rather than implicit joins in the where clause. Think of the where clause as where you filter based on various conditions (except for join conditions), and the join clause as where you put all join conditions. It helps organize your query's logic. In addition, you can only imply inner joins (in the where clause). The join clause is needed any time you want to work with outer joins (as in the case of your second query, above).

This is the same as your first query but with explicit join syntax:

```
select pname
from   parts p
  join catalog c
    on (p.pid = c.pid)
```

Comment: Oh perfect! Works like a charm! Thank you so much. Could you put a link to the documentation you read? Thankyou!

Comment: Thank you that will help a lot. Do you think the first query solution I have is correct? I think it is but I just wanted another opinion.

Comment: It would probably work but I posted a version that uses explicit join syntax